# Call win32 CreateProfile() from C# managed code

Tags: c#, winapi, pinvoke

Quick question (hopefully), how do I properly call the win32 function CreateProfile() from C# (managed code)?  I have tried to devise a solution on my own with no avail.

**The syntax for CreateProfile() is:**

```
HRESULT WINAPI CreateProfile(
  __in   LPCWSTR pszUserSid,
  __in   LPCWSTR pszUserName,
  __out  LPWSTR pszProfilePath,
  __in   DWORD cchProfilePath
);
```

The supporting documents can be found in the [MSDN library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762271(v=VS.85).aspx).

The code I have so far is posted below.

**DLL Import:**

```
[DllImport("userenv.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern int CreateProfile(
                      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszUserSid,
                      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszUserName,
                      [Out][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] StringBuilder pszProfilePath,
                      uint cchProfilePath);
```

**Invoking the function:**

```
/* Assume that a user has been created using: net user TestUser password /ADD */

// Get the SID for the user TestUser
NTAccount acct = new NTAccount("TestUser");
SecurityIdentifier si = (SecurityIdentifier)acct.Translate(typeof(SecurityIdentifier));
String sidString = si.ToString();

// Create string buffer
StringBuilder pathBuf = new StringBuilder(260);
uint pathLen = (uint)pathBuf.Capacity;

// Invoke function
int result = CreateProfile(sidString, "TestUser", pathBuf, pathLen);
```

The problem is that no user profile is ever created and CreateProfile() returns an error code of: *0x800706f7*.  Any helpful information on this matter is more than welcomed.

Thanks,
-Sean

**Update:**
Solved!
string buffer for pszProfilePath cannot have a length greater than 260.

Comment: The error codfe 0x800706f7 means: The Stub received bad data. Don't know if that helps.

Comment: @PVitt, Yes that's good to know but I don't know what I'm inputting wrong.

Comment: you don't need any of the MarshalAs attributes since you are just repeating the defaults.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the out parameter you should set the marshalling. More importantly, by passing a StringBuilder you already implicitly have an output parameter. Thus, it should become:

```
[DllImport("userenv.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern int CreateProfile(
                  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszUserSid,
                  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszUserName,
                  [Out][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] StringBuilder pszProfilePath,
                  uint cchProfilePath);
```

Calling this method:

```
int MAX_PATH = 260;
StringBuilder pathBuf = new StringBuilder(MAX_PATH);
uint pathLen = (uint)pathBuf.Capacity;

int result = CreateProfile(sidString, "TestUser", pathBuf, pathLen);
```

Comment: Should pszUserSid and pszUserName be marshalled as LPWStr?  They are defined as LPCWSTR where pszProfilePath is defined as LPWSTR..

Comment: Yes. An LPCWSTR is a const LPWSTR, i.e. the callee (CreateProfile) will not modify the passed string.

Comment: Alright, I updated my code based on your edit and for result I still receive 0x800706f7 but now for pathBuf I get "枀᮶".

Comment: And before that, what did you get?

Comment: Hmm. Did you try doing the same call from unmanaged code? I don't know the function, so perhaps something else (i.e. a different parameter) is wrong. I used the above method for other P/Invoke functions in my code, ex. GetClassName(), and it works fine. Also note that SetLastError probably shouldn't be used here, since there is no mentioning it in the MSDN documentation.

Comment: Okay, I'll take out the SetLastError.  And no, I haven't tried it from unmanaged code.  The values that I'm passing are as follows: for pszUserSid the string value "S-1-5-21-3136475479-1397610821-3514410724-1017" is passed and the rest is obvious.

Comment: After a lot of testing, I finally got it working locally. Apparently 1024 characters is too much. I gave it a length of 260 (MAX_PATH), and it worked.

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks for your help, Daniel!  You've solved my problem.  Where did you find the MAX_PATH declaration?

Comment: MAX_PATH is a general Windows variable used in unmanaged code all the time when accessing paths. It is the maximum length of a path. On a hunch I simply changed the value of the StringBuilder. Since the function seems quite "internal" to Windows, I guess they didn't add too much useful error output.

Comment: I didn't even consider that.  Its easy to overlook the obvious sometimes.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

It may not be the only problem but you need to add the `[Out]` attribute to the `pszProfilePath` parameter in your DLL import declaration.

Comment: I've added the [Out] attribute and it still didn't work.  I'm lost on what to try next.