# How to do "first login" style things via WinRM

Tags: windows, winapi, cygwin, winrm, msys2

So I'm working on a Chef cookbook for Windows, meaning it is generally executed on a Windows Server instance (2012r2 in this case). Specifically I am installing MSYS2 which uses Cygwin under the hood. I noticed that package installs were very slow and tracked down [an article](http://bjg.io/guide/cygwin-ad/) showing how the default nsswitch.conf in Cygwin uses the slower dynamic SAM/AD integration. For most users, and especially for my test environment this isn't needed so I tried following those steps to use only file-based users/groups. This resulted in a massive speedup (roughly 6x).

But there is a weirdness. It only works if I've logged in to the server via RDP at least once. Otherwise back to slows-ville.

Since this isn't hugely useful to automated testing, I've tried to figure out what exactly is causing the issue. The most likely candidate is that the first RDP connection (i.e. non-WinRM/headless session) is populating some piece of the user profile that headless sessions don't load, but I can't figure out what. I've tried calling `LoadUserProfile`, which is supposed to create a profile it doesn't exist, but this is not enough.

Any ideas on what piece of this I'm missing?

Comment: Not sure, but try CreateProfile function,  it was introduced in 2008 server.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762271.aspx http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813550/call-win32-createprofile-from-c-sharp-managed-code

Comment: Do you use: db_home: cygwin desc
db_shell: cygwin desc
db_gecos: cygwin desc. ?

Comment: Or db_home: windows desc  in your %MSYS2_DIR%\etc\nsswitch.conf ?

Comment: That is for creating a profile for a new user, unfortunately doesn't work on existing users. And the rest of the nsswitch is entirely the MSYS2 defaults.